# Crear consulta PDO con los valores de un array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Estoy tratando de generar una consulta `MySQL` con los datos que tengo capturados en un `array`.

```
array(2) {
    ["area1"] => array(3) { 
        [0] => string(5) "item1"
        [1] => string(5) "item2" 
        [2] => string(5) "item3"
    }
    ["area2"] => array(2) { 
        [0] => string(5) "item1"
        [1]=> string(5) "item2"} 
    }
}
```

¿Cuál es es el proceso para crear una consulta que quede tipo?:

```
"select nombre, tipo from tabla1 where area1 in(item1, item2, item3) and area2 in (item1, item2)"
```

¿Cómo sería el manejo de `bind` para estos posibles valores?

> **Nota:** El número de áreas y de items puede ser `n`, claro, todo esto con el formato de `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizando una consulta preparada de PDO, como en la siguiente liga

http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php

```
$paramsIn1 = [10, 203, 4, 6];
$paramsIn2 = [10, 203];

$strParams1 = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($paramsIn1), '?'));
$strParams2 = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($paramsIn2), '?'));

$sqlQuery = "select nombre,tipo from tabla1 where area1 in($strParams1) and area2 in ($strParams2)";

$sth      = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
$sth->execute(
    array_merge(
        $paramsIn1, $paramsIn2
    )
);
```

Para realizaro esto primero tienes que preparar la cadena y despues pasar los argumentos al metodo "execute".

La cadena tiene que ser preparada por que dependiendo del numero de parametros en el WHERE IN van a ser la cantidad de "?" en la cadena.

Comment: una duda: las áreas pueden ser area1,area2,area3,area4 osea puede ser n al igual que el valor de las áreas puede ser item1, item2,item3, por eso decía algo así como general una consulta porque hasta donde yo tengo es: select nombre,tipo from tabla1 where......de ahí para allá es donde no se, se me ocurre tratar de generar la cadenas con un foreach

Comment: Con el ejemplo que edite pueden ser N

Answer (score 0):

La clausula `IN` acepta una colección ,  así que podrías enviarle directamente los valores del `Array` separado por comas como un `String` , esto se logra haciendo uso de la función [implode(separador,array)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) , además encerrando todo esto en comillas simples *(concatenando)*

```
$array = array("area1"=> array("item1","item2","item1") , "area2"=> array("item1","item2"));
$area1 = "'".implode("','", $array['area1'])."'";
/* Convertimos a String ,separado por comas*/
$area2 =  "'".implode("','", $array['area2'])."'";
$sentencia = $mbd->prepare("SELECT nombre,tipo from tabla1 where area1 in  ( $area1 ) 
                            and area2 in ($area2)"); /* Le pasamos la colección*/
$sentencia->execute(); /* Ejecutamos la Sentencia */
$fila = $sentencia->fetchAll(); 
print_r($fila);
```

Answer (score 0):

buena tarde, termine haciendo esto:

```
public function procesarDestinatarios($array){
    $consulta = "select nombre,tipo from datosusuarios where ";        


    $aux1 = 1;
    $aux2 = 1;

    $count1 = count($array);
    $count2 = 0;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $count2 = count($array[$key]);
        $consulta .= $key ." in ("; 

        foreach ($value as $valor) {
            if($aux2 < $count2){
                $consulta .= "'".$valor ."',";
                $aux2++;
            }else{
                $consulta .= "'".$valor."'";
                $aux2 = 1;
            }

        }

        if($aux1 < $count1){
            $consulta .= ") and ";
        }else{
            $consulta .= ")";
        }

        $aux1++;
    }

    return $consulta;

}
```

lo que me resulto en esto:

```
 select nombre,tipo from datosusuarios where area1 in ('zona2','zona3') and grupo in ('a','c','d','h')
```

en primer lugar esa era la consulta que quería generar a partir del array, ahora estoy trabajando hace poco con PDO y se hace el uso del bind para el tipo de datos, como manejaría esto aquí, si estoy generando esa consulta dinamicamente por decirlo así.